# window.addEventListener(); is not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am just checking users online and offline status. I am using `window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);` . Its working on chrome and IE but not working on Firefox. When user goes online and offline below functions are calling.

```js
function updateOnlineStatus() {
 console.log('user is online');
}

function updateOfflineStatus() {
 console.log('user is offline');
}
```

Where i am doing wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: You need to show us the part of the code that you're referring to.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls these functions?

Comment: @Ahmad — It's in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: @Ahmad i am calling function using window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOfflineStatus);

Comment: "When user goes online and offline" — How are you defining "online and offline" Does it match Firefox's idea of what they mean?

Comment: [The documentation says that Firefox supports those events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events).

Comment: These events are supported in Firefox, check this out. https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status

Comment: Which version of Firefox and which operating system you refer to? Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) which explains differences between platforms and Firefox versions

Comment: @jakub.g i am using Firefox - 58.0.2 (64-bit) with windows 10.

Comment: This API returns false if you select "Work Offline" in firefox. Are you sure it will return false when there is no network? Even I turned off my network still it shows online. I couldn't trust it.

Comment: @Oktay yes exactly, also with me.

Answer (score -1):

Altought it should be supported in newer versions of Firefox try using the following:

```
$(window).bind("online", updateOnlineStatus); 
$(window).bind("offline", updateOfflineStatus);
```

Sidenote: This is jQuery so don't forget to link jQuery Library!

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but i need to fixed it using only pure javaScript.

Comment: Why would binding the event handlers with jQuery instead of the native functions help?

Comment: [As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: @Quentin If I'm not mistaken it's because all browsers support event bubbling but not all browsers support event capturing.

Comment: @someRandomSerbianGuy — IE 9 and earlier don't support capturing. The question is asking about Firefox. The code is not trying to use capturing. So support for capturing is irrelevant twice over.

Comment: @Quentin You should read my response to you again. jQuery .bind method uses event bubbling and NOT event capturing so we don't have to worry about supported/not supported browsers because event bubbling is supported by all of them.

Comment: @someRandomSerbianGuy — The code in the question uses event bubbling so how would switching to jQuery's `bind` method (which also uses bubbling) help?

Comment: @Quentin Oh you have point there. .addEventListener is working using bubbling capturing mode by default unless there is third parameter. I thought it was opposite (default: capturing, third par: bubble). My bad, nice catch!